# Error de instalacion de apk INSTALL_FAILED_USER_RESTRICTED android studio

Tags: android-studio

Estoy tratando de instalar una aplicación hecha con Android studio y al momento de finalizar la compilacion, salta el siguiente error.

```
Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED

List of apks:
[0] 'E:\otros\doormaid\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk'
Installation failed due to: 'null'
```

Mientras me sale ese error en el apartado de logcat me salen las siguientes lineas

```
2022-04-05 11:59:12.685 8569-8711/? E/CscParser: update(): xml file exist
2022-04-05 11:59:13.008 8569-8569/? E/IndicatorGardenAlgorithmBasicCutout: NOT MATCH !!!! resourceHeight:79, cutoutHeight:80 ([IndicatorGardenInputProperty]  Rotation(0-0,90-1,180-2,270-3)0, Density:3.0, ScreenWidthSize:1080, CoverSidePadding:0, mIndicatorGardenCenterOffset:13, mCameraCutoutCropSize:0, mGardenPaddingStart:24, mIndicatorCornerPadding:82, mCameraSidePadding:30, mCameraTopMargin:20, DpCutout:DisplayCutout{insets=Rect(0, 80 - 0, 0) waterfall=Insets{left=0, top=0, right=0, bottom=0} boundingRect={Bounds=[Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0), Rect(510, 0 - 570, 80), Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0), Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0)]} cutoutPathParserInfo={CutoutPathParserInfo{displayWidth=1080 displayHeight=2400 density={3.0} cutoutSpec={M 0,0 H -10 V 26.66666666666667 H 10 V 0 H 0 Z @dp} rotation={0} scale={1.0}}}})
```

Ya había hecho pruebas y no había tenido ningún problema. Quiero suponer que tiene algo que ver con el manifest.xml... se los comparto, Agradecería su ayuda

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.doormaid">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" android:required="true"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MICROPHONE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2" android:required="true"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone" android:required="true"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.audio.pro"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.audio.low_latency"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu aplicación no se puede instalar ya que presenta el error `INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED`, este indica que tu `AndroidManifest.xml`  tiene un error. Revisando el .xml al parecer es correcto actualmente, en este caso ve a :

`Build` > `Clean Proyect`

y genera nuevamente tu aplicación.